# How to connect to remote Queue Manager using MQExplorer 8.0

Tags: ibm-mq

I installed MQ8.0.0.4 on a ubuntu(14.4) server. I am able to launch a local MQ explorer and connect to local Queue Managers. I want to connect to the same Queue Manager from a remote windows machine. When I try this I get authorization errors:

> Access not permitted. You are not authorized to perform this operation. (AMQ4036)
>     Access not permitted. You are not authorized to perform this operation. (AMQ4036)
>     Severity: 10 (Warning)
>     Explanation: The queue manager security mechanism has indicated that the userid associated with this request is not authorized to access the object.

[This link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21250706) shows a list of auth commands to enable remote windows connection, but the page only lists upto version 7.5 for which this is applicable. Will I have to do the same setup on 8.0 as well?

I already enabled remote administration using the local MQ Explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The queue manager security mechanism has indicated that the userid associated with this request is not authorized to access the object."  Are you using the mqm ID or another ID?    You could use the [MQS_REPORT_NOAUTH](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&uid=swg21299319) or [MQSAUTHERRORS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21377578) setting to get more info the authority failure.

To answer your other question, I believe the settings in the link will also apply to v8 - but v8 also has additional new authority checks as well.

Comment: Thank you. The error I posted was with a mqm user. A non mqm user got a slightly different error. I had to disable a couple of CHLAUTH rules that blocked mqm users from accessing SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN channel and got it working.

Comment: FYI the MQS_REPORT_NOAUTH is on by default from 7.1 onward, this is even mentioned in Technote you provided `MQ 7.1, 7.5, 8.0: The MQS_REPORT_NOAUTH environment variable does NOT need to be set, as the trace is generated by default.`